# Language Modelling toolkit

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, language-model

I would like to build a [language model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model) for a text corpus. Are there good out-of-the-box toolkits which will alleviate my task? The only toolkit I know off is the Statistical Language Modelling(SLM) Toolkit by CMU.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

[NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) is very powerful, though I've never used it.

Comment: +1
Natural Language Processing Toolkit is your best choice.  Download from nltk.org  or buy the book from the Oreilly site.  It is close to a must-have. IMO.

Comment: I have used NLTK in the past but language models using NLTK is something which I never knew about.

Comment: http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.model.ngram.NgramModel-class.html

I finally got hold of the class but there seems to be no documentation for the same !

Comment: I can safely say NLTK is not really powerful after all. Reason: http://code.google.com/p/nltk/issues/detail?id=232

To be honest, it is absolutely disappointing to try doing something which is a "basic" model in machine learning and not just NOT implemented in NLTK but very few toolkits in popular languages like Java/Python around.

Answer (score 1):

The SRILM toolkit is very useful.

http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/

Answer (score 0):

[KenLM](https://kheafield.com/code/kenlm/) is also worth trying. It's fast and uses good default settings. In contrast to SRILM, it offers less options for configuration.